# "Text Link" plugin for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Is there a Chrome plugin that does what [Text Link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1939/) does for Firefox (linkifies links)?

Comment: You could... just select the text, right click and then say goto <url>

Comment: On the topic of Firefox text-to-link extensions, I'm quite fond of [Linkification](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/190/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Linkification](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cflchafndefoljnhhholeekfpgmbphaf)

[image]

> Linkification is inspired by the Firefox extension of the same name. It parses plain-text links on webpages and replaces them with actual hyperlinks. It is based on the 'Linkfy' bookmarklet.

Comment: Next time try to add at least 'some' information. Just posting a link doesn't tell us whether the solution you're linking to is any good.

Answer (score 3):

[BProd(uctive)](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/oiamoccpbchfhpiokdmojejefcnijhlk?hl=en) seems like what you're looking for.

> Linkify Text URL's:
>   Scans all text on loaded pages and makes non-clickable urls clickable and 
>   link them to the target url. On click url loads in new tab/window

---

Does [this](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fmhaaldakgddmknagfjphlliganfopii) work ?

Comment: It looks good, but appearantly it doesn't handle file URL (e.g. "http://///fileserver/Files/SomeFile.txt" which links to UNC \\fileserver\Files\SomeFile.txt)

Comment: Isn't that because that's a faulty address to start with? @ripper234

Comment: @Ivo - no, try putting it in an 'a href' tag and it works.

Comment: Updated @ripper

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. The author of BProd said he will add support for file links in about a week.